# Store: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ids') at selectIds

Tags: ngrx, store, state-management, ngrx-entity

What is causing the issue in the title. I am basically getting a typeError when I try to retrieve data in a feature store module.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I configurated wrongly the reducers in the StoreModule.forRoot inside the app.module.ts (I had multiple reducers so it should be declared in an object)